# Can you prevent StringTemplate output to stderr?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

Im currently using the following to output to a servlet using StringTemplate:

```
(ST)page.render();
```

When I do this, StringTemplate prints warnings to Stderr; filling up log files with useless warnings is not ideal.

If I understand the documentation correctly, will the following fix this:

```
STWriter out = new MyCustomWriter(response.getWriter());
page.write((STWriter)out, (STErrorListener)myListener);
```

And on a side note, will doing this save having to build an entire page of strings in memory?

Comment: Is this a question or confirmation that the doc is correct?

Comment: Have you tried modifying your templates to correct the warnings?

Comment: @TheANTLRGuy, yep its a question. I'll edit the subject.

Comment: @280Z28, Its a warning that I cant get rid of. (At least not anyway I can see)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put some time into digging through the javadoc and mucking around with the code, the following seems to suppress the errors completely:

```
page.write(new NoIndentWriter(response.getWriter()), new ErrorBuffer());
```

The ErrorBuffer simply collects all the warnings, which I can then ignore, or process if need be.

(I should post a separate question about if its possible to prevent this warning, but for now this works)

Comment: that is the correct solution. We generate errors and you are free to ignore or report the ones you want.